# how to fetch results all 7 days even if data not exist or exists in another month

Tags: mysql

Select query to results all 7 days even if data not exist or exists in another month.

I have two tables. first one is jobs and another one is dashboard_months
here is jobs table:

```
'id', 'job_amount', 'created_at'
'1', '50.0', '2018-04-16 11:01:36'
'2', '160', '2018-05-17 10:31:02'
'3', NULL, '2018-04-17 10:36:28'
'4', NULL, '2018-04-17 10:36:50'
'5', NULL, '2018-04-17 10:37:00'
'6', NULL, '2018-04-17 15:21:45'
'7', NULL, '2018-04-17 15:23:10'
'8', NULL, '2018-04-17 15:25:18'
'10', NULL, '2018-04-17 15:32:49'
```

and months table:

```
'id', 'month_name', 'm_type'
'1', 'January', '1'
'2', 'February', '1'
'3', 'March', '1'
'4', 'April', '1'
'5', 'May', '1'
'6', 'June', '1'
'7', 'July', '1'
'8', 'August', '1'
'9', 'September', '1'
'10', 'October', '1'
'11', 'November', '1'
'12', 'December', '1'
'13', 'Monday', '2'
'14', 'Tuesday', '2'
'15', 'Wednesday', '2'
'16', 'Thursday', '2'
'17', 'Friday', '2'
'18', 'Saturday', '2'
'19', 'Sunday', '2'
```

and I'm using this query to get `month_name` and `job_amount` sum.
query:

```
select
    dashboard_months.month_name,
    IFNULL(SUM(job_amount), 0) AS revenu
from
    dashboard_months
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    jobs ON dayname(jobs.created_at) = dashboard_months.month_name
where
    (dashboard_months.m_type = 2)
        AND (MONTH(jobs.created_at) = 4
        OR MONTH(jobs.created_at) IS NULL)
        AND (YEAR(jobs.created_at) = 2018
        OR YEAR(jobs.created_at) IS NULL)
group by dashboard_months.month_name
order by dashboard_months.id;
```

and Output:

```
'Monday', '50'
'Tuesday', '0'
'Wednesday', '0'
'Friday', '0'
'Saturday', '0'
'Sunday', '0'
```

and desired output:

```
'Monday', '50'
'Tuesday', '0'
'Wednesday', '0'
'Thursday', '0'
'Friday', '0'
'Saturday', '0'
'Sunday', '0'
```

you can see `Thursday` is missing because it is present in the 5th month.

```
'2', '160', '2018-05-17 10:31:02'
```

How can I get Thursday in every week?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
   dashboard_months.month_name,
    IFNULL(SUM(job_amount), 0) AS revenu
from
    dashboard_months
LEFT OUTER JOIN jobs 
ON dayname(jobs.created_at) = dashboard_months.month_name 
AND (MONTH(jobs.created_at) = 4
     OR MONTH(jobs.created_at) IS NULL) 
AND (YEAR(jobs.created_at) = 2018
        OR YEAR(jobs.created_at) IS NULL)
where dashboard_months.m_type = '2'
group by dashboard_months.month_name
order by dashboard_months.id;
```

**Output**

```
month_name  revenu
Monday      50
Tuesday     0
Wednesday   0
Thursday    0
Friday      0
Saturday    0
Sunday      0
```

**Demo**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/572b5b/20

Comment: you just remove month in where clause which is required.

Comment: because 160 is 5th month value not 4th month.

Comment: Thank you, bro, where was the mistake?

Comment: If you use those month and year condition in where then it will not take some records. So you have to provide the filter condition in `ON` clause so while taking left join you will not miss some records and in your case is `Thursday`.

Comment: Ok Thank You for the solution.